# Php 7 pdo mysql regexp whit variable into the query

Tags: php, mysql, regex, variables, pdo

I'm new to PHP and mySQL, I'm trying to play with this code to learn these languages.

I have this code:

```
<?php

class Cerca extends dbh{

  public function cercaArt(){
    $dbh = new dbh;
    $dbh->connect();

    if(isset($_POST['barcode']) || isset($_POST['codice']) || isset($_POST['descrizione'])){
      $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
      $codice = $_POST['codice'];
      $descrizione = $_POST['descrizione'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM articoli WHERE barcode = ? REGEXP \"^[$barcode]\"  OR codice = ? REGEXP \"^[$codice]\"  OR descrizione = ? REGEXP \"^[$descrizione]\" ";
      $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute([$barcode, $codice, $descrizione]);

      if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

          echo "<tr>
                <td>". $row['codice'] ."</td>
                <td>". $row['descrizione'] ."</td>
                <td>". $row['prezzoA'] ."</td>
                <td>". $row['prezzoV'] ."</td>
                <td>". $row['quantita'] ."</td>
                <td>". $row['barcode'] ."</td>
                <td>". $row['esaurimento'] ."</td>
                <td>". $row['categoria'] ."</td>
                </tr>
                ";
          }
        }
    } else{
      echo 'Immissione non valida!';
      }
  }
}
?>
```

and this is the form code for that script:

```
    <?php
include 'includes/header.php';
session_start();
include 'includes/sidebar.php';
include 'includes/dbh.php';
include 'includes/cerca-articolo.php';
 ?>

   <!-- Header -->
<header class="w3-container" style="padding-top:22px">
  <h4><b><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Anagrafica articoli</b></h4>
</header>

 <!-- CONTENT! -->

 <!-- FIRST ROW -->
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-bottom">
    <div class="w3-container w3-third">
      <form class="w3-container" action="anagrafica-articoli.php" method="post">
        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Barcode:</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="barcode" type="text">
        <br>
        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Codice articolo:</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="codice" type="text">
        <br>
        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Descrizione:</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="descrizione" type="text">
        <br>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-blue" type="submit" value="submit">Cerca</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="w3-container">
  <table class="w3-table w3-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Codice</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
      <th>Prezzo Acquisto</th>
      <th>Prezzo Vendita</th>
      <th>Quantità</th>
      <th>Barcode</th>
      <th>Esaurimento</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
      $search = new Cerca;
      $search->cercaArt();
     ?>
  </table>
</div>


 <?php
   include 'includes/footer.php';
  ?>
```

When I run it I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1139 Got error 'missing terminating ] for character
>   class at offset 3' from regexp in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bk\includes\cerca-articolo.php:16 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bk\includes\cerca-articolo.php(16):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bk\anagrafica-articoli.php(49): Cerca->cercaArt() #2
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bk\includes\cerca-articolo.php on
>   line 16

This query is for a search field. This works without the regexp but it doesn't show me data if the description or the barcode I search for is not complete.

If the description is "NIKE AIR SHOWS YELLOW" and I search for "NIKE" I don't get the data field show in the table.
For the the data I have to search "NIKE AIR SHOWS YELLOW" exactly string.

So I want to try to add a regexp for getting the data if I search only 1 word of the description, for example, or only a piece of barcode to show all articles have that piece of barcode inside but I get that error.

Comment: Echo your `$sql` after you generate it. There's something in the regex that mysql does not like.

Comment: Your regexp isn't doing what I would consider a partial search. It will be looking for 1 character at the start of the string. E.g. `nike` would match any string starting with `n`, `i`, `k`, or `e`. You might want to look into full text searching, that'll probably be easier and more reliable.

Comment: and how to make the search on full text searching? can you show me and example?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-improve-database-searches-with-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Comment: and how i setup this ALTER TABLE news ADD FULLTEXT (title, content, author); if i'm working on phpmyadmin and not in linux?

Comment: i have setup it

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM articoli WHERE MATCH(codice,descrizione,barcode) AGAINST(? ? ? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";

Comment: it work for the description

Comment: but not for codice and barcode

Comment: how to fix it now?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM articoli WHERE MATCH(codice,descrizione,barcode) AGAINST(? ? ? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";
      $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute([$codice,$descrizione,$barcode]);

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: yes if you see at the top in my code i use $stmt->execute([$barcode, $codice, $descrizione])